# Default radio button option with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to hide/show different divs using the method shown [here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-show-hide-div-using-radio-button).

```
<style>
    .box{
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #228B22; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
    label{ margin-right: 15px; }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
        $(".box").not(targetBox).hide();
        $(targetBox).show();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="red" checked = "checked"> red</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="green"> green</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="blue"> blue</label>
    </div>
    <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
</body>
```

I would like to have the red button clicked by default when the page loads. However if I just change the label to this:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="red" checked = "checked"> red</label>
```

It shows as clicked:
[image: checked but not showing]


but I have to click it again to actually load the red div:


[image: shows after clicking]


Is there an elegant way to fix that so it is showing the red div when the page loads?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Comment: Add `.click()` after the end of your event handler. E.g. `$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){...).click()`

Comment: Thanks j08691, I couldn't get this solution to work. Was probably something dumb I was doing, but You's solution worked without modification so I just did that.

Comment: Actually, the `.click()` alone at the end would've selected the last input. But adding `$("input:checked").click()` after your click handler would've done the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just adding the `$('.red').show()` to set which box should be shown as default?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    var inputValue = $(this).attr('value');
    var targetBox = $('.' + inputValue);
    $('.box').not(targetBox).hide();
    $(targetBox).show();
  });

  $('.red').show();
});
```

```css
.box {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.red {
  background: #ff0000;
}
.green {
  background: #228b22;
}
.blue {
  background: #0000ff;
}
label {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="red" checked> red</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="green"> green</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="blue"> blue</label>
    </div>
    <div class="red box">You have selected <strong>red radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue radio button</strong> so i am here</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked!